# Do I need Load Balancer for internal ReplicaSet

Tags: kubernetes

I can't find an answer - Do I need load balancer to communicate between replicas in my app? I want to have one gateway for outside communication and multiple different replicas. So all articles about load balancer in kubernates describe external load balancer, but don't understand does ReplicaSet has own load balancer (when one pod from ReplicaSet1 will make request to RepicaSet2, will it automatically balancing between replica's pods) or I need setup load balancer for internal communications manually.